# Send notification mail to "assign to"

Tags: workflow, web

I have a custom list created where users will add items.
I have the column "Assigned to" where i can enter the mail address.

I need to send automatically a notification mail for status change or new item added. Notification to be sent to mail input in assigned to.

I am using only web application, no designer or something else.
I tried workflow but it is not working.
My workflow window is like [image] and i didn't find a solution .

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Task lists in SharePoint have this built into the "Assigned To" field. Just go into the task list settings > advanced > Email Notification (Yes/No).

I wish there was a way to transfer this to other lists. (if anyone knows of a way to do that please share)

Therefore you may want to use the task list as your starting point and customize it to make it have all the columns you have in your custom list.

The other way would be to have someone make a workflow for you with SharePoint designer. (given they have permissions to do so)

Comment: i tested now, and it seems is working as i like. I would migrate all columns to new tasks list. thank you for your answer. Wondering if i can input a custom template ?

Comment: Make a view in each list that shows the same columns in the same order then you can use quick edit (datasheet) mode to copy / paste the data from one list to the other. However you will loose created/modified info from the original list if you do this.